# What does "that" in "take that" refer to?

Tags: underwater

Kepler Crew is on there way to the Midpoint Station on the mover:

> Captain: Paul, stop the cart. It's not gonna go in that kind of water.
> Stop it.
>
> Paul: That's a lot of water.
>
> Norah: The pumps are probably jammed.
>
> Emily: What happens if they don't turn back on?
>
> Paul: Anybody else wanna take **that**? No? In the book, Alice cried so
> much she almost drowned in her own tears. Luckily, she could swim.

What does "that" in "take that" refer to?

Comment: "That" refers to the question in the sentence prior. *"Anybody else wanna take that [question]"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anybody else wanna take that?

Means:

> Does anybody else want to answer that?

Which means:

> Please, someone answer that for me.